# What is Difference between autoscale and Resize EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, emr

Please explain me how I can re size the cluster using Python ?

Business Scenario : When there is shortage of memory on instance then add one core node 
When there is slow(No of task are in queue) processing add more task nodes 
when processing is complete remove these extra core and task nodes

what is difference between Autoscale and Resize cluster ?
Regards, 
Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Themis](https://github.com/atlassian/themis), an EMR autoscaling framework developed at Atlassian.

Current features include reactive autoscaling (based on current usage) as well as proactive autoscaling (based on predefined schedules).

The tool also comes with a simple Web UI and is very easy to configure.

Cheers